# How to extend Typescript interface with two another interfaces and add 'null' to one property

Tags: typescript

I have two TS interfaces:

```
interface Alpha { name: string; login: string; amount: string; }
```

and

```
interface Beta { id: number; name: string; login: string; amount: string; }
```

I would like to create the third interface Gamma which extends those two, add new field to it and make amount field can be null as well as a string:

```
interface Gamma extends Alpha, Beta { targetAmount: string | null, amount: string | null }
```

Those **amount: string | null** is not possible to do without extra actions. I've find a few answers here, but they are about extending types or 'nulling' all properties.

Answer (score 8):

You can create a type that combines `Alpha` and `Beta` (an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types)) omitting `amount` via the [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) utility type, then either extend that using `interface` syntax or add `targetAmount` and `amount` via intersection:

```typescript
interface Gamma extends Omit<Alpha & Beta, "amount"> {
    targetAmount: string | null;
    amount: string | null;
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIBsAOALOyDeyIcAthAFzIDOYUoA5gNzLoD29olNdITyprAK7gutBswC+AKCmhIsRCgBCEMHkLAAJpRCCSAI2jNiZUTz5sOIM+P4khI6mN6SZc6PCTIA4qRJ4IAA9IEE0qZAB5EmAwAB4MHDwAMmQVNQAaZAAiAWEwLIA+AilkUuQ1KHpVVHs8m15kAB8iQXR0RhKy3MduBiaWto6JDql0VWRAyl8Sf2QAXmKy5C1KABYAJnTO0pMKbMCsraXLTn3D7bsHMB1W9COyiqqwGqubtq3hqSA)

Or with `type` using an intersection instead:

```typescript
type Gamma = Omit<Alpha & Beta, "amount"> & {
    targetAmount: string | null;
    amount: string | null;
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIBsAOALOyDeyIcAthAFzIDOYUoA5gNzLoD29olNdITyprAK7gutBswC+AKCmhIsRCgBCEMHkLAAJpRCCSAI2jNiZUTz5sOIM+P4khI6mN6SZYAJ6YUAcVIk8ALzIAPIkwGAAPBg4eABkyCpqADTIAEQCwmCpAHzI8fhSyEXIalD0qqj2mTa8yAA+RILo6IyFxRmO3Az1jc2tEq1S6KrIAB6UviT+yEEFxchalAAsAExJbUUmFGmjqevzlpw7ext2DmA6Tej7xaXlYJXnl83rA1JAA)

Either way, `Gamma`'s `amount` ends up as `string | null`.

For what it's worth, here are some sections of the handbook contrasting interfaces and type aliases, and extending vs. intersection:

- [Differences Between Type Aliases and Interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces)
- [Interfaces vs. Intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#interfaces-vs-intersections)

Comment: Exactly! It works for me, thanks.

Comment: this answers deserve more upvotes, clean and simple explication ! Thank you